# Exibir posts do wordpress com SQL

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

Estou fazendo um site estático, onde todos os arquivos são em PHP, no entanto esse site tem um blog que deve ser gerenciável pelo Wordpress, aí vocês me perguntam e pro que não fazer tudo pelo Wordpress? pois é rsrsr ordem são ordens né.

Então tive a ideia de criar uma pasta chamada "noticias" onde irei instalar o Wordpress, então vai ficar dominio/noticias.

Só que eu preciso exibir as duas ultimas noticias na página inicial, ou seja fora do Wordpress, eu sei que vou ter que criar um arquivo para se conectar ao banco de dados e fazer o include na index.php e escrever uma sentença em SQL, mas sou muito leigo nisso, poderiam me da uma luz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> eu sei que vou ter que criar um arquivo para se conectar ao banco de
>   dados e fazer o include na index.php e escrever uma sentença em SQL

Você não precisa de nada disso. A partir da versão 4.7 você pode usar a [REST API do WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) pra puxar os dados. A única exigência é que esteja usando pretty-permalinks (qualquer coisa que não seja `seusite.com?p=342` por exemplo).

```
$posts = file_get_contents( 'http://seuwordpress.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts' );
```

`$posts` agora é um objeto JSON contendo os últimos posts do site. Equivalente ao que seria a página inicial.

Comment: pretty-permalinks é o mesmo que url amigável né? então quer dizer que com isso eu posso usar as funções sql nativas do Wordpress em qualquer página fora do Wordpress? vou já testar como isso funciona

Comment: isso, url amigável. Você não vai conseguir usar as funções nativas do WordPress. O que você pode fazer é requisições para os `endpoints` da API, que vão te retornar partes do conteúdo - como essa que eu mostrei. No link tem todos os `endpoints` disponíveis e exemplos de como fazer as consultas.

Comment: Na verdade é simplesmente como se vc estivesse consumindo um webservice externo, vc faz requisições e recebe respostas.

Comment: Consegui :D eu abrir o retorno dele com aquele programa Postman que organiza todo o código json e ele não mostra a image de destaque do post, saberia me dizer?

Comment: Ele não vai mostrar a imagem, vai trazer somente o ID e vc precisa fazer outro request pra buscar essa imagem pelo ID. Abra outra pergunta com essa dúvida se precisar.